# Sending email attachments in plain text format instead of base64

Tags: email, base64

I need to send an email. The requirements are as follows:

1. Plain text and not HTML (Message type)
2. Plain text and not base64 (Attachments, given that my attachments are all ASCII text files.)

How do I do this?

I use Debian 10 buster generic.

Comment: You seem to be mixing the content type (HTML vs plain text) with the encoding (base64 or not). Please can you [edit] your question to clarify

Comment: I've edited the question, please let me know if it's not clear. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, command-line mail user agents send e-mail in plaintext.  And there is no need to encode in Base64 an ASCII text file (encoding is done for binary content only).

So you can simply use this command:

```
mailx someone@domain.com < mytextfile.txt
```